# Guake terminal hiding on AltGr - can't type pipes

Tags: keyboard, guake

Today my [Guake Terminal](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/guake/) started acting up in a way I haven't seen before - every time I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (which on my Swedish keyboard is the right Alt, right next to <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> on the right-hand side) the terminal looses focus and hides. On my Swedish keyboard this is extremely inconvenient, since <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is used to type pipes (`|`)...

I did install some updates which required a restart of my system today, but IIRC that was only Ubuntu Base and nothing else. I don't know for certain if this behavior was present before the update - since the popup came up when I started my system, I didn't do much work before I installed them and rebooted.

I also took a look in the Guake preferences to see if there was anything fishy with the keyboard shortcuts, but <kbd>AltGr</kbd> isn't used at all, and all other shortcuts work as expected. <kbd>AltGr</kbd> works normally in other context, such as an actual Terminal window (opened e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or typing here in Chromium.

What could have caused this? How do i troubleshoot and/or fix it?

Comment: On english ones, it is the same shortcut - you could also try 'Shift'+\. Your problem might be it reading it 'AltGr' as 'Alt'

Comment: @wilf: I can't type Shift+\ either, as \ is typed using AltGr on my layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a workaround that actually *solves* the problem for me, if only temporarily<sup>1</sup>: restart the window manager. Using Unity, this can be done by running

```
compiz --replace &
```

in a terminal.

**But be careful!**

Compiz spits out an aweful lot of gore in the terminal - the first time I did this I forgot the `&` and my initial reaction to the gore was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - [killing my window manager](http://i.lvme.me/rri734x.jpg).

It is (supposedly, I never tried it myself) possible to recover, using tricks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<number> to get to a TTY terminal, and run

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace &
```

but tread carefully anyway. Save all your stuff before trying this, in case you do [something stoopid](http://i.lvme.me/rri734x.jpg) and need to reboot.

#### Credits:

I probably wouldn't have figured this out without looking in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/971462) which [falconer](https://askubuntu.com/users/221281/falconer) [brought to my attention](https://askubuntu.com/a/399533/18112).

---

<sup>1</sup>) I haven't had this problem since, though. Touch wood 'n' stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Try going into guake preferences and under the *General* tab make sure that *Stay on top* is checked and *Hide on lose focus* is unchecked. (Although these settings doesn't explain why it is hiding on <kbd>AltGr</kbd> they may help.)

**UPDATE:** I made up a series of commands to show us the passive grabs on a keystroke. (Unfortunately I couldn't find an easier way to show passive grabs as XF86LogGrabInfo only shows active grabs.) So please run this command and post its output so we can find out if something is grabbing that AltGr key:

```
xdotool keydown "ISO_Level3_Shift"; sleep 1; xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"; xdotool keyup "ISO_Level3_Shift"; tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

or just

```
xdotool keydown "ISO_Level3_Shift"; xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"; xdotool keyup "ISO_Level3_Shift"; tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

(The above code will trigger the AltGr keypress event, so your guake terminal will hide/unhide during the execution, so better to run this command from e.g. `gnome-terminal`. If guake doesn't hide/unhide then something is wrong with your layout as your AltGr is not mapped to ISO_Level3_Shift)

---

*Update as it looks like this maybe a layout problem.*

First I would just try switching to a different layout and test if AltGr is functioning well in an other layout (Dash->Keyboard Layout and press on the `+` sign to bring up other layouts.) You may try out a different swedish layout or a layout of another North/Eastern European language (At least I know that these are using AltGr, but of course don't switch to a cyrillic, like Russian or Serb.) Though it is unlikely that the problem is with some of the official layouts, more likely it is a problem with some fine-tuning of an official layout. So if you modified your layout in some way remove those modifications and check again.

Next you can test with `xev` the keysym what your AltGr is reporting. Launch `xev`, click in its window, press AltGr, see the output. But if it causes a Focus-Out event then it likely won't catch it. In this case try with `xev -root` to monitor the root window, maybe you altgr is going there. (This latter won't draw a window, so just press AltGr and see if there is some useful output.)

You can also dump your keyboard layout with `xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb` then examine the output.xkb file with a text editor, it should contain this

```
key <RALT> {
    type= "ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
};`
```

(At least for me it does contain that and my AltGr is working correctly.)

You can also check if your keyboard has some modifier key which is turned on and maybe changes the behaviour of the AltGr.

---

*Update 3, I think this is the most likely situation in your case*

Please also check if you are maybe hit by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/971462

Though I never had that kind of problem with the HUD, some people looks like have it.

There is a workaround in that bugreport's conversation:

> System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Key to show the HUD
>   to your right Alt key.

But of course it is better if you change it to your left Alt-key, don't know why he proposes the right. For me at that option I indeed have `Alt L` by default.

You may also try to disable that shortcut totally.

Comment: *Stay on top* was already checked. Unchecking *Hide on lose focus* does indeed let me type pipes in the terminal, but I don't like the behavior - I want it to hide when it looses focus, but I don't want it to loose focus on AltGr :P It's a good workaround until I figure out something better, though.

Comment: @TomasLycken That means some application (likely some gnome app) is capturing the AltGr sequence before it reaches guake. We have to find out which app/process is the guilty for that.

Comment: Is there a good (i.e. easy) way to find that out, that you know of? (Yes, I'm in slightly over my head here...)

Comment: @TomasLycken I advise you to type "shortcut" in Dash and open the keyboard settings app. And on the shortcuts tab check for shortcuts which contain something like "Level3 Shift". Normally this is the symbol for AltGr. If you find one, that is the guilty one. You may also try editing or changing your layout settings, but first see if there is a hotkey set.

Comment: @TomasLycken I updated my answer with a method for finding out if something is grabbing that key.

Comment: I did that - there was nothing between the lines `[  1813.909] (II) Printing all currently active device grabs:` and `[  1813.909] (II) End list of active device grabs`.

Comment: @TomasLycken And did the guake terminal hide while you ran the command? Because it should hide in your case. If it doesn't hide for this command, but hides for AltGr then it is a problem with your layout.

Comment: No, it doesn't hide, even if I re-activate "hide on lose focus", so I guess this is a layout problem then. I noticed this is also a problem in some other cases - for example, when renaming an event in Shotwell I lose focus when pressing AltGr. (It doesn't happen when renaming e.g. a folder in Nautilus...) I'm using a Swedish keyboard layout. Any idea how to keep troubleshooting?

Comment: @TomasLycken I updated my answer with some troubleshooting steps. That is interesting that in some apps you lose focus in some other you don't. Only nautilus is the one which behaves correctly?

Comment: @TomasLycken I added one more update to my answer, I think this latter is the most likely problem in your case, though I was never hit with that bug.

Comment: By some reason  "Hide on lose focus" was activated, probably after updated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Workaround:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>
2. Release <kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Type the key you want

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I observe the same problem since recently (Ubuntu 13.10). I have also a Swedish keyboard, but the issue remains even if I change the keyboard layout.
I tested the command:  `xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb` but everything seems correct.